# Alamofire custom reponse migration from Alamofire v1.3 to 3.0 (and Swift 2 syntax)

Tags: swift2, alamofire

I am converting an project from Swift 1.1 to Swift 2.0 that used Alamofire 1.3.
Because this version of Alamofire was not compatible with Swift 2.0, I switched to the very last version of Alamofire (3.1.x).

However this broke the code, I am now getting the error message

"Cannot call value of non-function type 'NSHTTPURLResponse?'"

which is due to my my extension to create a custom "responseShop" Alamofire.Request.

How can this Alamofire.Request extension correctly be converted to the Alamofire 3.x/Swift 2.0 syntax?

```
extension Alamofire.Request {
    func responseShop(options: NSJSONReadingOptions = .AllowFragments, var errorHandler:ProtocolWebServiceErrorHandler?, completionHandler: (ShopCallResult?, WebServiceErrorCode) -> Void ) -> Self {
        objc_sync_enter(communicationLockObj)
        return response(serializer: Request.JSONResponseSerializer(options: options), completionHandler: {
            (request, response, JSON, error) in
            log.verbose("\(JSON)")
            //network error?
            if let error = error {
                //is it cancelled?
                if error.code == -999 {
                    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
                        //call handler with cancelled code
                        completionHandler(nil, WebServiceErrorCode.requestCancelled)
                    }
                    objc_sync_exit(communicationLockObj)
                    return
                }

                dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
                    errorHandler?.handleWebServiceError(WebServiceErrorCode.connectError, errorText : error.localizedDescription, request: request, json: JSON)
                    //call and supply org error
                    completionHandler(nil, WebServiceErrorCode.connectError)
                }
                objc_sync_exit(communicationLockObj)
                return
            }
            if JSON == nil {
                dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
                    errorHandler?.handleWebServiceError(WebServiceErrorCode.jsonNil, errorText: nil, request: request, json: JSON)
                    //call and supply org error
                    completionHandler(nil, WebServiceErrorCode.jsonNil)
                }
                objc_sync_exit(communicationLockObj)
                return
            }
            //api return error?
            let callResult = ShopCallResult(json: JSON!)
            if callResult.statusCode.failed {
                dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
                    errorHandler?.handleWebServiceError(callResult.statusCode, errorText: callResult.statusCode.localizedText, request: request, json: JSON)
                    completionHandler(callResult, callResult.statusCode)
                }
                objc_sync_exit(communicationLockObj)
                return
            }
            //no error
            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
                completionHandler(callResult, WebServiceErrorCode.OK)
            }
            objc_sync_exit(communicationLockObj)
        })
        return self
    }
}
```

Comment: You no longer need to specify Json serializer .  Try to replace `response` with  `responseJSON{   response in      debugPrint(response)   }`
Look at an example here
https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire/blob/master/Documentation/Alamofire%203.0%20Migration%20Guide.md#response-serializers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the feedback of @ProblemSolver I managed to convert the code, now it looks like this:

```
extension Alamofire.Request {

    func responseShop(queue: dispatch_queue_t? = nil, options: NSJSONReadingOptions = .AllowFragments, errorHandler:ProtocolWebServiceErrorHandler?, completionHandler: (ShopCallResult?, WebServiceErrorCode) -> Void ) -> Self {
        //enter thread protected area...
        objc_sync_enter(communicationLockObj)

        return responseJSON() {
            response in
            switch response.result {
            case .Success(let JSON):
                //log json in verbose mode
                log.verbose("\(JSON)")
                //parse the returned json
                let callResult = ShopCallResult(json: JSON)
                //is it failed?
                if callResult.statusCode.failed {
                    //call supplied error handler on the main thread
                    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
                        errorHandler?.handleWebServiceError(callResult.statusCode, errorText: callResult.statusCode.localizedText, request: self.request!, json: JSON)
                        completionHandler(callResult, callResult.statusCode)
                    }
                    //release the lock
                    objc_sync_exit(communicationLockObj)
                    //processing done!
                    return
                }
                //no error call handler on main thread
                dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
                    completionHandler(callResult, WebServiceErrorCode.OK)
                }
                //release the lock
                objc_sync_exit(communicationLockObj)

            case .Failure(let error):
                //WARNING: cancelled is still error code 999?
                //is it cancelled?
                if error.code == -999 {
                    //just call the completion handler
                    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
                        //call handler with cancelled code
                        completionHandler(nil, WebServiceErrorCode.requestCancelled)
                    }
                    //release the lock
                    objc_sync_exit(communicationLockObj)
                    //stop furhter processing
                    return
                }
                //error with the json?
                if error.code == Alamofire.Error.Code.JSONSerializationFailed .rawValue {
                    //call the error handler
                    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
                        errorHandler?.handleWebServiceError(WebServiceErrorCode.jsonNil, errorText: nil, request: self.request!, json: nil)
                        //call and supply org error
                        completionHandler(nil, WebServiceErrorCode.jsonNil)
                    }
                    //release the lock
                    objc_sync_exit(communicationLockObj)
                    //stop further processing
                    return
                }
                //must be some other kind of network error
                dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
                    log.error("\(error)")
                    //so call the error handler
                    errorHandler?.handleWebServiceError(WebServiceErrorCode.connectError, errorText : error.localizedDescription, request: self.request!, json: nil)
                    //call and supply org error
                    completionHandler(nil, WebServiceErrorCode.connectError)
                }
                //release the lock
                objc_sync_exit(communicationLockObj)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I am not really sure about the reason for the locking but you could use the `defer` syntax from `Swift 2` for `objc_sync_exit` call. instead of repeating it 5 times.

Comment: The idea behind the locking is that only one web service call should be active at one time (they should be serialized...). Not sure if the locking accomplishes this to be honest... as we are already using a queue